# Chrome onErrorOccurred listener not firing on Linux

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've got a simple Chrome background page extension which listens for a error loading a page then tries to refresh the page. This normally works fine on Windows and Linux but under Linux it wont work when loading the first page on startup. i.e. if you have a home page set and you open chrome and that page is not available it will never refresh.

It seems that the listener is only registered after the home page is loaded and the error has already occurred.

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function(details) {
  // ignore subframes, images, scripts etc
  if (details.type !== "main_frame")
    return;

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: details.url});
  }, 5000);
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?